# Jasmine unit test for angular service In controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm new to jasmine framework. I've gone through some tutorials and learned and started writing unit tests. 'facing one issue here is the description.
I have a controller where i can invoke a service call to get the data. See the code below.

```
$scope.getEmpInfo = function() {
  EmpService.getInfo($scope.empid)
     .then(function(data) {
        $scope.empData  = data;
        $scope.populateEmpData($scope.empData);
     }, function(reason) {
        //do nothing
    } 
}
```

Now, i  want to write a unit test for the above method. Im able to make a spy on serice using promise but i wasnt able to spy `$scope.populateEmpData()`. here is my test case.

```
    describe('Emp data', function() {
       var d, scope;
       beforeEach(function() {
          module("emp");
          module("emo.info");
       });
       describe('empcontroller', function() {
          beforeEach(inject(function($q,_EmpService_, $controller,$rootScope){
              d = $q.defer();
              empService = _EmpService_;
              spyOn(empService,"getInfo").and.returnValue(d.promise);
              scope = $rootScope.$new();
              empCtrl = $controller("empController", {
                $scope: scope,
              });
           }));
         it('should get the Employee information ', function() {
                scope.getEmpInfo();
                spyOn(scope,'populateEmpData');
                expect(EmpService.getInfo).toHaveBeenCalled();
                //Here im getting the error.
                expect(scope.populateEmpData).toHaveBeenCalled();
         });

       });
   });
```

Please help resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you not able to spy on it? `spyOn(scope, 'populateEmpData');`

Comment: @fqhv thanks for the response.I forgot to add that. I already added that but test got failed.

Comment: When you add that what is the error?

Comment: i added first time itself. the error is "Expected spy populateEmpData to have been called."

Comment: You're never resolving your promise. And you're not calling scope.$apply() after resolving it. So the promise callback is never called.

Comment: thanks @JBNizet. Can u please explain a bit more. and how can achieve this if i have sync calls back to back upon success of every service call.

Comment: Read the section about testing in http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/06/04/angularjs-promises-2/

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are not resolving promise. You will have to make change in spyOn.

```
 - spyOn(empService,"getInfo").and.callFake(function() {
            return {
                  then : function(success, error) {
                     success();
                }  
         } }

Now, it will go into the success callback and will try to call $scope.populateEmpData();
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response. getting another error          
 `$scope.getEmpInfo = function() {
  EmpService.getInfo($scope.empid)
     .then(function(data) {
        $scope.empData  = data[0];
        $scope.populateEmpData($scope.empData);
     }, function(reason) {
        //do nothing
    } 
}`  Im getting data[0] is undefined. while running test cases

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data[0]') - This is the error im getting. it referring my method.

Comment: It;s beacause, You have not passed any data in success call.

var data = ['anydata'];


spyOn(empService,"getInfo").and.callFake(function() {
            return {
                  then : function(success, error) {
                     success(data);
                }  
         } }

Answer (score 0):

You're never resolving your promise. And you need to call $scope.$apply().

> Why is this necessary? Because any promises made with the $q service
>   to be resolved/rejected are processed upon each run of angular’s
>   digest cycle. Conceptually, the call to .resolve changes the state of
>   the promise and adds it to a queue. Each time angular’s digest cycle
>   runs, any outstanding promises will be processed and removed from the
>   queue.
>   [Unit Testing with $q Promises in AngularJS](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/07/13/unit-test-promises-angualrjs-q/)

Check it out above link it will help you.