# .then is not a function Angularjs factory

Tags: jasmine

I just started learning Jasmine test cases for angularjs. I am unable to test below code.Kindly help

```
$scope.getConstants = function(lovName) {
    ConstantService.getConstants(lovName).then(function(d) {
        switch (lovName) {
        case 'WORKFLOW':
            $scope.workflowTypes = d;
            $scope.loadCounterpartyTmp();
            break;
            --------Other Cases
            }
```

My ConstantService is defined as

```
 App.factory('ConstantService', [ '$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {

return {
    getConstants : function(lovName) {
        return $http.post('/sdwt/data/getConstants/', lovName).then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        }, function(errResponse) {
            return $q.reject(errResponse);
        });
    }
```

I want to test getConstants function.I need to create a mock of ConstantService and pass the data to it.

I have written below test case but the test case is not working.Please let me know how to test the above code

```
  describe('getConstantsForMurexEntity', function() {
            it('testing getConstantsForMurexEntity function', function() {

   var d=[];
                d.push(
                    {id:1,value:'ABC'},
                    {id:2,value:'DEF'},
                    {id:3,value:'IJK'},
                    {id:4,value:'XYZ'},
                       );
                   //defined controller
                    spyOn(ConstantService, 'getConstants').and.returnValue(d);

                $scope.getConstants('WORKFLOW');
                expect($scope.workflowTypes).toBe(d);
```

The above test case is not working as it is saying "ConstantService.getConstants(...).then is not a function".

Comment: I have added a similar answer here : [Mock factory call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43928466/7941292)

Answer (score 1):

Your `ConstantService.getConstants()` function returns a promise, which your actual code is using, with the `.then()` call. This means means that when you spy on it, you also need to return a promise, which you are not doing. Because you are not returning a promise, when your actual call tries to call `.then()`, it is undefined, which is the reason for the error message.

Also, you aren't using `Array.push` correctly.

Your test should probably look something like the following (note, this is untested):

```
describe('getConstantsForMurexEntity', function() {
  it('should set workflowTypes to the resolved value when lovName is "WORKFLOW"', inject(function($q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    spyOn(ConstantService, 'getConstants').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

    var d = [
      {id:1,value:'ABC'},
      {id:2,value:'DEF'},
      {id:3,value:'IJK'},
      {id:4,value:'XYZ'},
    ];

    $scope.getConstants('WORKFLOW');

    deferred.resolve(d);
    $scope.$apply();

    expect($scope.workflowTypes).toBe(d);
  }));
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thankyou for the reply. I have used the above code while tried to run the test case it is saying $scope.workflowTypes is undefined. Can you please tell why it is undefined.

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, I'm afraid I can't guess why. I'd try to narrow it down to which line, either by debugging, or sprinkling console.logs around the code.